# Cannot select bone influence in Unity

Tags: unity, sprites

In my sprite editor, under the weights menu, the option for bone influence appears kinda faded and I am not able to select it. Unity is also not generating automatic weights around my bones for different sprites in the same image. Is this feature only available in the pro version, or is there some other setting that is causing the problem?

Comment: Walk us through the steps you took to get here, and show us a screenshot of the current state in the editor.

Comment: @DMGregory I made a .png file of a stickman and made it's background transparent. Then I opened it in the sprite editor and sliced it so that only the stickman was left. Added some bones, and then clicked on Generate in Auto Geometry, with the weights checkbox ticked. The mesh and the weight distribution showed up, but I am only able to use Weight slider and weight brush to edit it because I can't click on bone influence. I'll now add the screenshot.

Comment: @DMGregory Sorry, I think that I have deleted that file. Can you please try to help me with the above information?

Comment: Questions about debugging a problem in your game must include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. If you've deleted the file, make a new one for example purposes. Ensure your question is so clear that a stranger will be able to reproduce your problem starting with a new empty Unity project, using only the text and images you've provided — because that's generally exactly what we'll have to do before we can test solutions. The more follow-up questions we have to ask, the longer you have to wait for useful answers.

Comment: @DMGregory okay I will create a new file

Comment: You don't need to report back to me, just edit your question and I'll remove the comments once they're no longer relevant.